Azure Container Apps - Restrict API access with managed identities
I have a .NET Core API app running in Azure Container Apps (ACA), I want to restrict access to it to only allowed authentication by managed identity, MS Doc mentions it's possible, but no details.
On the high level, I want to offload the authentication to Azure without code changes on the client and the API.
On the API side, I've tried enabling Authentication in ACA with "Microsoft" as IdP type.
On the client side, I've enabled System Assigned Managed Identities.
I need some help on how to link the two together.

DefaultAzureCredential will automatically authenticate with managed Identity present in Azure Container app only for User assigned managed identity you will have to provide its client ID in your code.
I have tried creating one containerized console app and pushed it to Azure Container app using system assigned managed identity with DefaultAzureCredential:-
using Azure.Identity;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" }));

        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token.Token}");
    }
}

Dockerfile:-
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ManagedIdentityConsoleApp/ManagedIdentityConsoleApp.csproj", "ManagedIdentityConsoleApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./ManagedIdentityConsoleApp/ManagedIdentityConsoleApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ManagedIdentityConsoleApp"
RUN dotnet build "./ManagedIdentityConsoleApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./ManagedIdentityConsoleApp.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ManagedIdentityConsoleApp.dll"]

Azure Container app:-
az containerapp update --name siliconapp9 --resource-group rgxxxxxxe --image siliconacr9.azurecr.io/managedidentityconsoleapp:dev
>az containerapp ingress enable --name siliconapp9 --resource-group rgxxxxxxe --type external --target-port 80




Refer the statement below from this Github Document:- for azure-sdk-for-net, Azure.Identity

Managed Identity - If the application is deployed to an Azure host with Managed Identity enabled, the DefaultAzureCredential  will authenticate with that account.


interesting, so this approach allows client app to get a token from IdP without using client_credential, and with proper configuration, token can be validated by ACA's built-in authentication sidecar.  This is a good low-code approach, is there a no-code approach that client-app itself doesn't need to manually acquire a token?
